# Python - How to quickly pull several attributes from an object?

Tags: python, attributes, exec

I have a proprietary `job` object that has several non-method string attributes that I would like to be able to compile into a list efficiently. The `job` object has an attribute `TAGS` that includes the full list of attribute names that I would like to compile the values for, but has no method for pulling just the values. I'm looking for a way to leverage the `TAGS` list to efficiently pull all the needed string attributes.

```
>>> job_object.TAGS
('date', 'id', 'name', 'state', 'starttime', 'endtime', 'runs', ...) # There are 9 in all
```

I can pull the attributes individually, but I would like to have an efficient implementation and would rather not hard code just in case the `TAGS` changes.

```
>>> job_object.id
'1426013702'
```

I've tried using `exec` but it, of course, doesn't return anything.

```
>>> [exec('job_object.{}'.format(tag)) for tag in job_object.TAGS]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Is there another way to pull these without call each attribute explicitly?

Comment: are you able to edit the class for job_object ? could you add a  `def __str__(self):
        return list_of_desired_tags`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I couldn't get `exec` to work as you expect either.

However, this seemed to work:

```
print([getattr(job_object, tag) for tag in job_object.TAGS])
```

However, I've just looked up the documentation for `exec()` and it always returns `None`.